# Existence of solution of a PDE via ranked distributions

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to find out whether the following PDE has a solution $f(x,y)$ in an open neighborhood of the origin for positive values of $f(0, 0)$ -
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = f \cos(y) \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = - f \log(f) \tan(y)
\end{equation}$$
The approach I want to use is to define the vector fields -
$$\begin{equation}
X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - f\cos(y) \qquad Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + f\log(f)\tan(y) 
\end{equation}$$
Would the correct steps be to show that $X$ and $Y$ span a rank $2$ distribution and then, via the lie bracket $[X, Y]$, show that it is or isn't involutive (and thus integrable if the answer is yes)?

Comment: My knowledge of differential geometry is extremely rusty, but I am also curious about this question. Would you be willing to explain in which sense $X,Y$ are vector fields?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I think the idea is that $X$ and $Y$ should be viewed as descriptions of the tangent plane to the graph of $f$, although I'm not too sure about rewriting them in this form, hence why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so… If my understanding is correct, the two equations generate vector fields on $\mathbb R^3_+$ (with variables $x,y,z$, $z>0$) of the form
$$X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ z\cos(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, $$
$$Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-z\log(z)\tan(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}. $$
As you said, these vector fields are supposed to span the graph of $f$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

What they span has obviously rank two, so we look at the Lie bracket.
$$ [X,Y]=(X(Y^3)-Y(X^3))\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=[-z\cos(y)(\log(z)+1)\tan(y)+z\sin(y)+z\log(z)\sin(x)]\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=0. $$
This implies that the distribution is indeed involutive, so you can apply Frobenius theorem and find a surface that is tangent to $X$, $Y$ close to the point $(0,0,z)$, for $z> 0$. This surface is the graph of $f$, which will be a solution of your PDE. This procedure is essentially equivalent to taking the original equations and checking that the mixed derivative of $f$ obtained by differentiating the first equation in $y$ and the second in $x$ give the same quantity.

The vector fields are smooth on $\mathbb R^3_+$, so if you ask for $f(0,0)>0$, you should have no problem with the above argument.

Comment: Could you please clarify the computation of the Lie bracket? I might be making an error in my calculations and somehow got stuck, yet this should be the trivial step.

Comment: So, I am using that on $\mathbb R^n$, one has $[X,Y]=\sum_n (X(Y^n)-Y(X^n))\partial_{x_n}$, where $X=\sum_nX^n\partial_{x_n}$ so, since all components of $X$ and $Y$ are constant exept for the $z$ component, the first equality in my answer follows. Then, $X(Y^3)$ is just the $z$-derivative of $Y^3$ multiplied by $X^3$, since the $x$ derivative of $Y^3$ is zero, while the other term $Y(X^3)$ is made by the two terms $Y^2\partial_y(Y^3)+Y^3\partial_z(Y^3)$, which give the remaining two terms after simplifying a bit (in particular, I use multiple times that $\tan(y)\cos(y)=\sin(y)$).